# How to add grid cell width 0 for some dimensions

Tags: css, material-ui

What to use instead of `mdl-cell--0-col-phone` to disable element or make it zero width?

```
<div className="mdl-grid">
  <div className="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-cell--2-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-desktop">
    <LeftContent/>
  </div>
  <div className="mdl-cell mdl-cell--0-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--8-col-desktop">
    <!-- no content -->
  </div>
  <div className="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-cell--2-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-desktop">
    <RightContent/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class

```
mdl-cell--hide-phone
```